# How to check matches between two files

Tags: unix, awk, match, multiple-columns

I have two text files with 2 columns each with tabs, and I would like to find the matches between them. The files have columns in opposite order for the information that I want to check.

File 1:

```
B.1      Av1
Q7       G3
Q9       S4
```

File 2:

```
Av1     B.1
G3      Q7      
S8      Q9
```

The output should be:

```
B.1      Av1     match
Q7       G3      match
Q9       S4      no match
```

I know that I could change the order of the columns in the file 2 and them compare with file 1 using diff or awk, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way to compare the files that I do not need to change the column positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk without changing the order of the columns:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} {printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, $2 in a ? "match" : "no match"}' file2 file1
B.1      Av1    match
Q7       G3     match
Q9       S4     no match
```